# Building (or just getting) latest libvirtd for virtiofs on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: libvirt

Please note I'm *really* new to kvm and libvirt, so may be missing something really fundamental here. Apologies if this is really a 'read the FAQs' type question, but I didn't find anything concrete so far.

Installing libvirt on Ubuntu 18.04 via apt installs version 4.0.0. I need to share host folders with guests and wanted to ensure decent performance so thought I'd give virtiofs a go. The docs suggest minimum 6.2 for this (indeed, just putting `<driver type='virtiofs'/>` into the guest config results in a failure to validate against the schema).

I downloaded the libvirt sources, but couldn't find a comprehensive list of pre-requisites. I ended up installing these to get `configure` to run without complaining:

```
apt install gcc libglib2.0-dev gnutls-dev libxml2-dev xsltproc python-docutils libdevmapper-dev libpciaccess-dev
```

I then ran `../configure --without-macvtap` (since I'm using bridge networking).

At this point, I can run `make check`, but end up with a string of compile errors in `util/libvirt_util_la-virnetdev.lo` (full error output below). I'm assuming I still have some missing pre-requisites, but I couldn't find a full list anywhere, and googling for this error didn't turn up much either. Are there some build instructions somewhere I'm missing?

```
# make check
make  check-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
Making check in .
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
make  check-local
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
make  all-recursive
make[4]: Entering directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
Making all in .
make[5]: Entering directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
Making all in include/libvirt
make[5]: Entering directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build/include/libvirt'
make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[5]: Leaving directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build/include/libvirt'
Making all in src
make[5]: Entering directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build/src'
make  all-am
make[6]: Entering directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build/src'
  CC       util/libvirt_util_la-virnetdev.lo
../../src/util/virnetdev.c: In function 'virNetDevGetFamilyId':
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2980:12: error: variable 'gmsgh' has initializer but incomplete type
     struct genlmsghdr gmsgh = {
            ^~~~~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2981:10: error: 'struct genlmsghdr' has no member named 'cmd'
         .cmd = CTRL_CMD_GETFAMILY,
          ^~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2981:16: error: 'CTRL_CMD_GETFAMILY' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'U_CHARSET_FAMILY'?
         .cmd = CTRL_CMD_GETFAMILY,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                U_CHARSET_FAMILY
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2981:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2981:16: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2981:16: note: (near initialization for 'gmsgh')
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2982:10: error: 'struct genlmsghdr' has no member named 'version'
         .version = DEVLINK_GENL_VERSION,
          ^~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2982:20: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
         .version = DEVLINK_GENL_VERSION,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2982:20: note: (near initialization for 'gmsgh')
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2983:10: error: 'struct genlmsghdr' has no member named 'reserved'
         .reserved = 0,
          ^~~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2983:21: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
         .reserved = 0,
                     ^
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2983:21: note: (near initialization for 'gmsgh')
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2980:23: error: storage size of 'gmsgh' isn't known
     struct genlmsghdr gmsgh = {
                       ^~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2985:23: error: 'CTRL_ATTR_MAX' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'DEVLINK_ATTR_MAX'?
     struct nlattr *tb[CTRL_ATTR_MAX + 1] = {NULL, };
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       DEVLINK_ATTR_MAX
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2989:20: warning: implicit declaration of function 'nlmsg_alloc_simple'; did you mean 'g_regex_split_simple'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if (!(nl_msg = nlmsg_alloc_simple(GENL_ID_CTRL,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    g_regex_split_simple
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2989:20: warning: nested extern declaration of 'nlmsg_alloc_simple' [-Wnested-externs]
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2989:39: error: 'GENL_ID_CTRL' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'G_ASCII_CNTRL'?
     if (!(nl_msg = nlmsg_alloc_simple(GENL_ID_CTRL,
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       G_ASCII_CNTRL
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2990:39: error: 'NLM_F_REQUEST' undeclared (first use in this function)
                                       NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_ACK))) {
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2990:55: error: 'NLM_F_ACK' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'N_6PACK'?
                                       NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_ACK))) {
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~
                                                       N_6PACK
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2995:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'nlmsg_append'; did you mean 'g_list_append'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if (nlmsg_append(nl_msg, &gmsgh, sizeof(gmsgh), NLMSG_ALIGNTO) < 0)
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
         g_list_append
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2995:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'nlmsg_append' [-Wnested-externs]
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2995:53: error: 'NLMSG_ALIGNTO' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'CMSG_ALIGN'?
     if (nlmsg_append(nl_msg, &gmsgh, sizeof(gmsgh), NLMSG_ALIGNTO) < 0)
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                     CMSG_ALIGN
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2998:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'nla_put_string'; did you mean 'g_hmac_get_string'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if (nla_put_string(nl_msg, CTRL_ATTR_FAMILY_NAME, family_name) < 0) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         g_hmac_get_string
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2998:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'nla_put_string' [-Wnested-externs]
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2998:32: error: 'CTRL_ATTR_FAMILY_NAME' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'CTRL_ATTR_MAX'?
     if (nla_put_string(nl_msg, CTRL_ATTR_FAMILY_NAME, family_name) < 0) {
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                CTRL_ATTR_MAX
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3004:61: error: 'NETLINK_GENERIC' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'NETLINK_MSG_PUT'?
     if (virNetlinkCommand(nl_msg, &resp, &recvbuflen, 0, 0, NETLINK_GENERIC, 0) < 0)
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                             NETLINK_MSG_PUT
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3007:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'nlmsg_parse'; did you mean 'umsg_parse'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if (nlmsg_parse(resp, sizeof(struct nlmsghdr), tb, CTRL_ATTR_MAX, NULL) < 0) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
         umsg_parse
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3007:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'nlmsg_parse' [-Wnested-externs]
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3007:34: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct nlmsghdr'
     if (nlmsg_parse(resp, sizeof(struct nlmsghdr), tb, CTRL_ATTR_MAX, NULL) < 0) {
                                  ^~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3013:12: error: 'CTRL_ATTR_FAMILY_ID' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'CTRL_ATTR_FAMILY_NAME'?
     if (tb[CTRL_ATTR_FAMILY_ID] == NULL) {
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            CTRL_ATTR_FAMILY_NAME
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3018:31: warning: implicit declaration of function 'RTA_DATA'; did you mean 'NO_DATA'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     *family_id = *(uint32_t *)RTA_DATA(tb[CTRL_ATTR_FAMILY_ID]);
                               ^~~~~~~~
                               NO_DATA
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3018:31: warning: nested extern declaration of 'RTA_DATA' [-Wnested-externs]
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3022:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'nlmsg_free'; did you mean 'g_list_free'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     nlmsg_free(nl_msg);
     ^~~~~~~~~~
     g_list_free
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3022:5: warning: nested extern declaration of 'nlmsg_free' [-Wnested-externs]
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2985:20: warning: unused variable 'tb' [-Wunused-variable]
     struct nlattr *tb[CTRL_ATTR_MAX + 1] = {NULL, };
                    ^~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:2980:23: warning: unused variable 'gmsgh' [-Wunused-variable]
     struct genlmsghdr gmsgh = {
                       ^~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c: In function 'virNetDevSwitchdevFeature':
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3046:12: error: variable 'gmsgh' has initializer but incomplete type
     struct genlmsghdr gmsgh = {
            ^~~~~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3047:10: error: 'struct genlmsghdr' has no member named 'cmd'
         .cmd = DEVLINK_CMD_ESWITCH_GET,
          ^~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3047:16: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
         .cmd = DEVLINK_CMD_ESWITCH_GET,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3047:16: note: (near initialization for 'gmsgh')
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3048:10: error: 'struct genlmsghdr' has no member named 'version'
         .version = DEVLINK_GENL_VERSION,
          ^~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3048:20: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
         .version = DEVLINK_GENL_VERSION,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3048:20: note: (near initialization for 'gmsgh')
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3049:10: error: 'struct genlmsghdr' has no member named 'reserved'
         .reserved = 0,
          ^~~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3049:21: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
         .reserved = 0,
                     ^
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3049:21: note: (near initialization for 'gmsgh')
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3046:23: error: storage size of 'gmsgh' isn't known
     struct genlmsghdr gmsgh = {
                       ^~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3078:39: error: 'NLM_F_REQUEST' undeclared (first use in this function)
                                       NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_ACK))) {
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3078:55: error: 'NLM_F_ACK' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'N_6PACK'?
                                       NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_ACK))) {
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~
                                                       N_6PACK
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3083:53: error: 'NLMSG_ALIGNTO' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'CMSG_ALIGN'?
     if (nlmsg_append(nl_msg, &gmsgh, sizeof(gmsgh), NLMSG_ALIGNTO) < 0)
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                     CMSG_ALIGN
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3088:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'nla_put'; did you mean '_IO_putc'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if (nla_put(nl_msg, DEVLINK_ATTR_BUS_NAME, strlen("pci")+1, "pci") < 0 ||
         ^~~~~~~
         _IO_putc
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3088:9: warning: nested extern declaration of 'nla_put' [-Wnested-externs]
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3095:61: error: 'NETLINK_GENERIC' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'NETLINK_MSG_PUT'?
     if (virNetlinkCommand(nl_msg, &resp, &recvbuflen, 0, 0, NETLINK_GENERIC, 0) < 0)
                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                             NETLINK_MSG_PUT
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3098:34: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct genlmsghdr'
     if (nlmsg_parse(resp, sizeof(struct genlmsghdr), tb, DEVLINK_ATTR_MAX, NULL) < 0) {
                                  ^~~~~~
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3105:10: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
         *(int *)RTA_DATA(tb[DEVLINK_ATTR_ESWITCH_MODE]) == DEVLINK_ESWITCH_MODE_SWITCHDEV) {
          ^
../../src/util/virnetdev.c:3046:23: warning: unused variable 'gmsgh' [-Wunused-variable]
     struct genlmsghdr gmsgh = {
                       ^~~~~
Makefile:10841: recipe for target 'util/libvirt_util_la-virnetdev.lo' failed
make[6]: *** [util/libvirt_util_la-virnetdev.lo] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build/src'
Makefile:6443: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[5]: *** [all] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build/src'
Makefile:777: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
Makefile:670: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
Makefile:1070: recipe for target 'check-am' failed
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
Makefile:777: recipe for target 'check-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/libvirtd/libvirt-6.4.0/build'
Makefile:1072: recipe for target 'check' failed
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this is probably caused by the `--without-macvtap` arg to configure. I expect you've triggered a combination of `#ifdef` checks that are not correct. Even if you're going to use bridge networking, there's no harm in letting libvirt build macvtap support, so just remove the `--without-macvtap` arg as a first attempt to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer—running plain `../configure` led to some more missing dependencies, and after installing _those_, I was able to configure `--without-macvtap` and build. So I'm guessing this is a combination of not having a published list of dependencies easily available, and a small bug where `configure` doesn't pick up on a required dependency being missing. I'm going to post an answer with all the required bits listed, unless you want to update yours and then I'll happily mark it as accepted, as your original thought certainly led me to the right place...

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, and thanks to @danielb for suggesting including `macvtap`, it seems *these* are the minimum packages that need to be installed to successfully build on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
apt install gcc libglib2.0-dev gnutls-dev libxml2-dev xsltproc python-docutils libdevmapper-dev libpciaccess-dev libnl-3-dev libnl-route-3-dev
```

Note the scenario in my original question did not include `libnl-3-dev` or `libnl-route-3-dev`, and whilst `configure` would run happily without those, `make` would not.

Comment: BTW, in general  `apt-get build-dep libvirt`  will be a good starting point - that installs everything that the distro vendor uses as pre-requisites for libvirt. Even though the distro libvirt is older, the pre-requisites don't change often, so `build-dep` will get you most of the way there.

Comment: Thanks for that—is that just 'common knowledge', or was that on the libvirt pages somewhere that I didn't spot?